# How can I remove the clock from the Irssi status bar?

Tags: irssi

I'm using Irssi nested in Byobu. Since Irssi has an inbuilt clock, the Irssi window gets marked for activity every time a minute rolls over. Byobu has its own clock, so the feature is not useful to me.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `/statusbar window remove time` to remove it.
You can also use `/statusbar window reset` to reset the statusbar.
see also
http://irssi.org/beginner/#c12

Comment: EL magnefico! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Simply run this:

```
/statusbar window remove time
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers: If you want to permanently remove the clock, edit ~/.irssi/config. Navigate its hierarchy:

- Look for the toplevel `statusbar = {` line.
- Look inside it for the line `default = {`; it will most likely be indented two spaces and situated after the block starting with `items = {`.
- Nested within the `default = {` block, find `items = {`.
- Within that find the line `time = { };`. Comment that line out or delete it.